# RSpec 'specify' passes with explicit subject, but not with implicit subject

Tags: ruby, rspec

I thought I understood how implicit subjects work in RSpec, but I don't.

Why is it that in the following example, the first spec with an explicit subject passes, but the second spec using an implicit subject fails with "undefined method `matches' for #":

```
class Example
  def matches(str) ; true ; end
end

describe Example do
  subject { Example.new }
  specify { subject.matches('bar').should be_true }
  it { matches('bar').should be_true }
end
```

(I'm using rspec 1.3, but I verified the same behavior with 2.10.1.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Step back to some basic ruby: You're basically calling `self.matches`, and `self` in this case is an RSpec example.

You can call things like "should" on this example, with parameters, so you might try something like:

```
it { should matches('bar') }
```

but this will fail; there's no method `matches` on self still!

In this case, though, the subject really is the `matches` method, not the Example instance. So, if you want to continue using the implicit subject, your tests might be something like:

```
class Example
  def matches(str) ; str == "bar" ; end
end

describe Example do
  describe "#matches" do
    let(:method) { Example.new.method(:matches) }

    context "when passed a valid value" do
      subject { method.call("bar") }
      it { should be_true }
    end

    context "when passed an invalid value" do
      subject { method.call("foo") }
      it { should be_false }
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Nice. Your clarification of putting the call to 'matches' inside the subject block (and parametrizing it for different examples) cleared it right up! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can call any methods of implicit subject. Implicit subject meanings you don't need to specify the subject, but if you want call any method you need to specify the subject.

Answer (score 0):

Although Chris provided very nice answer, I recommend you to take a look at this blog post: http://blog.davidchelimsky.net/2012/05/13/spec-smell-explicit-use-of-subject/